# Bootstrap 4 toggler not opening on click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

im trying to add a toggler(bootstrap4) but it is not opening on click. When adding the code straight from the bootstrap page it only adds a button that encloses the menu but it is not working to open up. Also searched but found no answer, care to help?
html:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/RPC-JP_Logo.png" width="62" height="62" alt="">
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
  <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Nosotros</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Negocios</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Oportunidades</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Enlaces de Interes</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">RSC</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</nav>

css:

.navbar {
min-height: 125px;
}

.navbar-nav {
padding: 80px 0 0;
}

.nav-link {
font-size: small;
font-weight: 900;
text-align: center;
}

.nav-item {
padding: 0 15px;
}

.navbar-brand {
width: 97.5vw;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

.navbar-brand img {
display: block;
margin: 13px auto;
}
```

Comment: I learned it is due to css styling but have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Below code seems to do the trick. Made the following changes

- Brought `navbar-toggler` before `navbar-brand`
- Added `mx-auto` class to `navbar-brand` to center align
- Removed absolute positioning by removing css for `navbar-brand`

```css
.navbar {
min-height: 125px;
}

.navbar-nav {
padding: 80px 0 0;
}

.nav-link {
font-size: small;
font-weight: 900;
text-align: center;
}

.nav-item {
padding: 0 15px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
display: block;
margin: 13px auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/RPC-JP_Logo.png" width="62" height="62" alt="">
          </a>



        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Nosotros</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Negocios</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Oportunidades</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Enlaces de Interes</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">RSC</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you it is very useful, now the logo does not center in full page width.

Comment: @Lz504 Please accept and close this answer if it resolves our original question